# In Pandas how do I select rows that have a duplicate in one column but different values in another?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
import pandas as pd
records = [{'Name':'John', 'Country':'Canada'}, {'Name':'John', 'Country':'Canada'}, 
       {'Name':'Mary', 'Country':'US'}, {'Name':'Mary', 'Country':'Canada'}, 
       {'Name':'Mary', 'Country':'US'}, {'Name':'Stan', 'Country':'UK'},
       {'Name':'Stan', 'Country':'UK'}]
df = pd.DataFrame(records)
df
```

```
Name        Country
0   John    Canada
1   John    Canada
2   Mary    US
3   Mary    Canada
4   Mary    US
5   Stan    UK
6   Stan    UK
```

I want to test for Names that have differing values for Country. In this case, I only want to see Mary, since she has both US and Canada in the country column. I can exclude John and Stan since both of their records are for the same country.

Any ideas how to accomplish this?

Comment: `df.drop_duplicates()`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First step is to find the names that have more than 1 unique `Country`, and then you can use `loc` on your dataframe to filter in only those values.

**Method 1: `groupby`**

```
# groupby name and return a boolean of whether each has more than 1 unique Country
multi_country = df.groupby(["Name"]).Country.nunique().gt(1)

# use loc to only see those values that have `True` in `multi_country`:
df.loc[df.Name.isin(multi_country[multi_country].index)]

   Name Country
2  Mary      US
3  Mary  Canada
4  Mary      US
```

**Method 2: `drop_duplicates` and `value_counts`**

You can follow the same logic, but use `drop_duplicates` and `value_counts` instead of groupby:

```
multi_country = df.drop_duplicates().Name.value_counts().gt(1)

df.loc[df.Name.isin(multi_country[multi_country].index)]

   Name Country
2  Mary      US
3  Mary  Canada
4  Mary      US
```

**Method 3: `drop_duplicates` and `duplicated`**

**Note**: this will give slightly different results: you'll only see Mary's unique values, this may or may not be desired...

You can drop the duplicates in the original frame, and return only the names that have multiple entries in the deduped frame:

```
no_dups = df.drop_duplicates()

no_dups[no_dups.duplicated(keep = False, subset="Name")]

   Name Country
2  Mary      US
3  Mary  Canada
```

Comment: Well done, this saved me some thinking!

Answer (score 2):

First you can groupby `Name` column then combine group `Country` column into list. Then check if values in this list are all the same.

Moreover, you can use boolean indexing to select the rows which have different values.

```py
s = df.groupby('Name')['Country'].agg(list).apply(lambda l: all(map(lambda x: x == l[0], l)))

df_ = df[df['Name'].isin(s[~s].index)].drop_duplicates()
```

```
print(df_)

   Name Country
2  Mary      US
3  Mary  Canada
```