# How to find columns in duplicated rows where are different values in DataFrame in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I have DataFrame in Python like below where we can see duplicates for some ID:

| ID | COL1 | COL2 | COL3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | XX | 111 | ENG |
| 123 | abc | 111 | ENG |
| 444 | ccc | 2 | o |
| 444 | ccc | 2 | o |
| 67 | a | 89 | xx |

And I need to select rows where is situation like for ID = 123, where rows are duplicated but in some column / columns we have different value, so as an output I need something like below:

| ID | COL1 | COL2 | COL3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | XX | 111 | ENG |
| 123 | abc | 111 | ENG |

How can I do that in Python Pandas? I can add that in my real dataset I have many many more columns so I need to create solution whoch will be good for more columns not only ID,COL1,COL2,COL3 :)

Comment: Your question is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67231430/in-pandas-how-do-i-select-rows-that-have-a-duplicate-in-one-column-but-different

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Pandas how do I select rows that have a duplicate in one column but different values in another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67231430/in-pandas-how-do-i-select-rows-that-have-a-duplicate-in-one-column-but-different)

Comment: Ari Lupin, Rene - mentioned questions do not answered my question, because i have many more columns, I mentioned quesitons there are only 1 columns with possible different values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first drop duplicates for all columns then find duplicates for id column. finally select same ids.

```
df = df.drop_duplicates()
mask = df.duplicated(subset=['ID'],keep=False)
df = df[mask]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [.query](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html)

```
df = df.query("ID.eq(123)").drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)
print(df)

    ID COL1  COL2 COL3
0  123   XX   111  ENG
1  123  abc   111  ENG
```

Unless you aren't also trying to filter:

```
df = df.drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)
print(df)

    ID COL1  COL2 COL3
0  123   XX   111  ENG
1  123  abc   111  ENG
2  444  ccc     2    o
3   67    a    89   xx
```

Comment: This only works when the id field is equal to 123.

Comment: Yeah hard to understand what you wanted exactly thats why I also gave a non filtering version.

Answer (score 0):

here is one way to do it

```
# drop the duplicates
df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)

# groupby ID and filter the ones where group size is greater than 1
df[df.groupby('ID')['ID'].transform('size')>1]
```

```
    ID  COL1    COL2    COL3
0   123     XX  111     ENG
1   123     abc     111     ENG
```

alternately,

```
# preserve the original DF and create a secondary DF with non-duplicate rows
df2=df.drop_duplicates()

# using loc, select the rows in DF2 that has a group size exceeding 1
df2.loc[df2.groupby('ID')['ID'].transform('size')>1]
```